# Running Time Nested For Loops

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity, big-o

I must find the running time of the following function.

```
S=0 
For i=4 to n^2 
    For j=5 to 3*i*log(i) 
       S=S+i-j 
Return S
```

So far I believe the running time **T(n)=((n^2)-3)*(3*i*log(i)-4)** but I can't get the second part in terms of n.  I've also figured out that the max it can be or the big O notation is **((n^2)-3)*(3*(n^2)*log(n^2))** that is if **n^2** was the value of i for every iteration through the inner loop, but this is not the case, which basically tells me it can be written **O((n^4)*log(n^2))**.  To figure out the big theta value I've been trying to calculate an average value for **3*i*log(i)** to use as the value of i for every iteration but I can't seem to figure that out.

Any suggestions? Or other methods to tackle this?

Comment: assuming i = j = 1, my works out lead to a answer roughly equal to 
log(BIG_PI(i^i))  where 1<=i<=n^2.   I do not know how to continue but I think the answer should be way larger then you expected...

Answer (score 1):

Using Sigma notation is an efficient way to formally come up with your algorithm's order of growth:

[image]